# How to find data on MongoDB by passing part of array objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I tried to create an API for filtering the products by sending an array of objects as filters.
this is my Product schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { s, rs, rn, rref, ref } = require("../utils/mongo");

let schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: rref("user"),
    name: rs,
    description: s,
    images: [s],
    price: rn,
    category: ref("category"),
    filters: [
      {
        parent: ref("filter"),
        value: s,
        name: s,
      },
    ],
    subFilter: [
      {
        parent: s,
        value: s,
        title: s,
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("product", schema);
```

and this one is what I want to send as body to the API

```
{
  category: '62445c3d922d127512867245'
  filters: [
    { name: 'filter name 1', value: '62445c3d922d127512861236' },
    { name: 'filter name 2', value: '62445c3d922d127512861458' },
    .....
  ]
}
```

as you see I want to filter my products based on category Id and an array of filter objects. I tried to write this query but it return an empty array.

this is my query:

```
filter: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { category, filters } = req.body;

      const products = await Product.find({
        category,
        filters: {
          $in: filters,
        },
      });

      res.status(200).json(products);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  },
```

what stored on db

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62643acf19636d7db1804cb3"), 
    "images" : [
        "image-1650735823476۸.jpg"
    ], 
    "user" : ObjectId("622606af0f40cb8ea37383dc"), 
    "name" : "شیر توپی 2 اینچ کلاس 150 پیشگام", 
    "description" : " برند پیشگام با مدارک و تاییدیه ", 
    "price" : NumberInt(5000000), 
    "category" : ObjectId("62445c4d922d127512867246"), 
    "filters" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("62643acf19636d7db1804cb4"), 
            "parent" : ObjectId("6264307f19636d7db1804b77"), 
            "value" : "626430bb19636d7db1804b78", 
            "name" : "Valve Type"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("62643acf19636d7db1804cb5"), 
            "parent" : ObjectId("6264319819636d7db1804b7b"), 
            "value" : "6264319819636d7db1804b7e", 
            "name" : "Body Type"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("62643acf19636d7db1804cb6"), 
            "parent" : ObjectId("626431ef19636d7db1804b82"), 
            "value" : "626431ef19636d7db1804b83", 
            "name" : "Bore Type"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("62643acf19636d7db1804cb7"), 
            "parent" : ObjectId("6264328519636d7db1804b85"), 
            "value" : "6264328519636d7db1804b86", 
            "name" : "Material Type"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("62643acf19636d7db1804cb8"), 
            "parent" : ObjectId("626435de19636d7db1804c10"), 
            "value" : "626439b619636d7db1804ca7", 
            "name" : "Trim Material"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("62643acf19636d7db1804cb9"), 
            "parent" : ObjectId("6264367919636d7db1804c17"), 
            "value" : "6264367919636d7db1804c18", 
            "name" : "End Conection"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("62643acf19636d7db1804cba"), 
            "parent" : ObjectId("626436a719636d7db1804c1f"), 
            "value" : "6264378119636d7db1804c28", 
            "name" : "Size"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("62643acf19636d7db1804cbb"), 
            "parent" : ObjectId("6264389219636d7db1804c6d"), 
            "value" : "6264389219636d7db1804c6f", 
            "name" : "Class / Pressure"
        }
    ], 
    "subFilter" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("62643acf19636d7db1804cbc"), 
            "parent" : "6264328519636d7db1804b85", 
            "value" : "626433b919636d7db1804b93", 
            "title" : "Body Material"
        }
    ], 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-04-23T17:43:43.421+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-04-23T17:53:29.016+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Comment: Can you share the attempted query, sample docs. It would be simple direct match with or without positional operator.

Comment: the last code block related to my query @Gibbs

Comment: We need to see 1 example of the doc in MongoDB so we can see exactly what `categories` and `filters` fields look like.

Comment: $in compares whole objects. If you have more than name and value stored in mongo, you need to use $elemMatch for partial comparison: `filters: {$or: filters.map(f=>({$elemMatch: f}))}`

Comment: I updated the question and added what I stored on DB @BuzzMoschetti

Comment: OK -- When you pass filters as inputs in the API, do you want them to `AND` in the query, i.e. the filters array in the doc must contain *all* of the inputs, or does it need to match only *at least one*?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I need only at least one, I mean `name` and `value`

Comment: Why are `parent` and `_id` fields of type `ObjectId` but `value` is a string?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this shrunk down set of inputs that capture the essence of the question.  The comments "give away" what we are going to try to find and why.  We only show one value for `category` because matching on that is trivial and not the interesting part of the query.

```js
[
{
    "category" : ObjectId("62445c4d922d127512867246"),
    "filters" : [
        // Matching Valve/value; include this doc                                     
        {"name" : "Valve", "value" : "626430bb19636d7db1804b78"},
        // ALSO match Body/value; include this doc (but needs only 1 match)           
        {"name" : "Body",  "value" : "6264319819636d7db1804b7e"}
    ]
}

,{
    "category" : ObjectId("62445c4d922d127512867246"),
    "filters" : [
        // Not target value for Valve name (..79 instead of ...78):                   
        {"name" : "Valve", "value" : "626430bb19636d7db1804b79"},
        // ...but correct value for Body, so include this doc                         
        {"name" : "Body",  "value" : "6264319819636d7db1804b7e"}
    ]
}

,{
    "category" : ObjectId("62445c4d922d127512867246"),
    // No matching Valve or Body so this whole doc is ignored.                        
    "filters" : [
        {"name" : "Valve", "value" : "626430bb19636d7db1804b79"},
        {"name" : "Body",  "value" : "6264319819636d7db1804b7f"}
    ]
}
,{
    "category" : ObjectId("62445c4d922d127512867246"),
    // Not even name matches so ignore this too:                                      
    "filters" : [
        {"name" : "Pipe",  "value" : "6264319819636d7db1804eee"}
    ]
}

]
```

Assume also we set up inputs coming from the API like this, in their native form i.e. strings NOT `ObjectId`:

```js
var targ_cat = '62445c4d922d127512867246';

var any_one_of = [
    { name: 'Valve', value: '626430bb19636d7db1804b78' },
    { name: 'Body', value: '6264319819636d7db1804b7e'}
];
```

We will use `$filter` as our main function but to do so, we must convert the incoming material into a form required by `$filter`.

```js
// Convert inbound array of any_one_of into a something designed to work              
// in the $filter function by comparing each name/value entry in the                  
// filters field to the item presented in $$this, meaning take:                       
//    { name: 'Valve', value: '626430bb19636d7db1804b78' },                           
// and turn it into:                                                                  
//    {$and: [ {$eq:['Valve','$$this.name']}, {$eq:['62643...','$$this.value']} ] }   
// Since any one of the entries is considered a hit, we package it all
// into an $or wrapper, not $and.
                                                                                 
var or_list = [];
any_one_of.forEach(function(f) {
    or_list.push( {$and: [
        {$eq:[f['name'], '$$this.name']},
        {$eq:[f['value'], '$$this.value']}
    ]});
});
var or_expr = {$or: or_list};
```

Now we are ready to query mongoDB:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    // Get this out of the way quickly; note we must make a new ObjectId!                                              
    {$match: {'category': new ObjectId(targ_cat)}}

    // The interesting part of the query:
    ,{$addFields: {filters: {$filter: {input: '$filters', cond: or_expr}}}}

    // Only keep those items where $filter found at least one of the                  
    // targets:                                                                       
    ,{$match: {$expr: {$gt:[{$size: '$filters'},0]} }}
]);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works but has an issue, I need all filters to match the query, not find products that have one of the filter objects. filtered products should exactly match the filters array.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.   Edit your question.

Comment: @M.AminAzimi I second Buzz, your comment is quite confusing. Appreciating language barrier, could you update the question with examples that illustrate how the answer is wrong. You are using `$in` operator which means "match any value from array in the query", and in your case - match at least one filters subdocument to any item from the API request.

Comment: I don't want to find at least one filter, I need all selected filters to match with filtered product filters @AlexBlex

Comment: Please edit your question and show an example of how your inputs from the API should find *and not find* matches in the DB.   The word "filter" shows up too much in your explanations and we are having a difficult time understanding "what is what."